# Android Manifest error - No resource identifier found for attribute 'documentLaunchMode' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to use a library project in my app. I add its reference & build the code. It gives no error.

However, when i try running the app i get an exception the manifest file generated within the bin folder of my app. The error is -

AndroidManifest.xml:39: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'documentLaunchMode' in package 'android'

My apps min & target SDK versions are -

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Whereas the library projects min & target SDK versions are-

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

Kindly suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set your build target (`compileSdkVersion` in `build.gradle`, or in Eclipse use Project > Properties > Android) to 21 or higher, as that attribute was only added in API Level 21 (Android 5.0).